# inputKey basic sample doesn't work

Tags: sbt

My goal is to have a task or setting that can take some parameters.

After carefully reading [the docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Combined+Pages.html#Input+Tasks), I've written in `build.sbt` this basic snippet that compiles ok:

```
val servers = token(
    literal("desarrollo") | 
    literal("parametrizacion")
)

val deploy = inputKey[Unit]("Deploy to server")
deploy := {
    val serv = servers.parsed
    println(s"Deploying to $serv")
}
```

I'm experiencing this problems from SBT command line:

```
> deploy desarrollo
[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: deploy
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Expected key
[error] Expected '::'
[error] Expected end of input.
[error] Expected 'desarrollo'
[error] Expected 'parametrizacion'
[error] desploy desarrollo
[error]          ^
```

Tab completion for the argument doesn't work.

My purpose is to admit a parameter whose value can be `desarrollo` either `parametrizacion`.

Comment: I've just discovered that the syntax expected by SBT is `deploydesarrollo` and `deployparametrizacion`.

Answer (score 0):

A space must be specified and discarded.

```
val servers = token(' ' ~> (
    literal("desarrollo") | 
    literal("parametrizacion")
))

val deploy = inputKey[Unit]("Deploy to server")
deploy := {
    val serv = servers.parsed
    println(s"Deploying to $serv")
}
```

Now, `deploy desarrollo` and `deploy parametrizacion` do work.

Really, the need to specify the initial space, provides more flexibility. :-)